# On node edit form, how to edit field from a referenced entity?

Tags: entities

I've got a master entity (node) that users edit, and I've got an entity reference on it. I'd like to be able to edit a field on the referenced entity on that master referencing entity's edit form.

Is there a module for this? Or can somebody just give me a general sense of a good way to accomplish this?

I know I can create a custom form element with hook_form_alter, then use a form_submit function, and then use entity_metadata_wrapper to load and save values.

That seems cumbersome, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can use [Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) to get the referenced entity's fields and then hide what you need to hide and/or change the form's structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.drupal.org/project/references_dialog or https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form.

The first one will load the referenced entity in a popup, the other will show it as part of the original form.